# C ++ class error

Tags: c++, class, warnings, instance

i have this code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class time{
            public:

             time();        //constructor

             void settime(int,int,int);

             void print();

      private:

              int hour,min,sec;

              };

//constructor

time::time(){

             hour=min=sec=0;

             }

int main(){

    int num;

    time t1;//line1

    time t2;//line2

    cout<<"hello"<<endl;

    cin>>num;

    return 0;}
```

and the errors in those lines are:

expected `;' before "t1"

[Warning] statement is a reference, not call, to function `time'

for each line

whats the problem???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `std::time` function that is imported into the global namespace by your use of `using namespace std;`.  This conflicts with your class named `time`.  This is yet another good reason never to use `using namespace std;` at namespace scope.

Note, however, that not all standard library implementations respect the rule that names in the standard library that come from the C standard library should not be placed in the global namespace by default.

Another option is to qualify the name `time` with `class`, which will allow this to work on any system:

```
class time t1;
class time t2;
```

You might also just consider renaming your class.

Comment: ... or putting your own time class into a namespace of your own to make it distinct from anything at global scope.